# Get processes running for a particular user in Windows Server 2016 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2016

How to get the process list user-wise in Windows Server 2016 using PowerShell?

I mean `Get-Process` would give me the list of running processes, but that is for the machine.
I want the process list for individual users who're logged-in to the machine.

Comment: `Get-Process -IncludeUserName`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-IncludeUserName` switch to request resolution of the process owner identity:

```bsh
Get-Process -IncludeUserName
```

Comment: Is there any other alternative to that, since this requires administrative privileges and I don't want that.